# how to write this query from 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hear no relation have 2 table

1. "employee Table"

columns

```
Empid    Empname    Salary    Age
1        abc        2000      20
2        xyz        3000      26
3        ijk        4000      32
4        mno        5000      50
```

1. "Groupname" table

columns

```
Groupid    Groupname   Min  Max
1          young       18   25  
2          middle      26   35   
3          old         36   60
```

then i need result using both tables

empid empname age group
1   abc 2000 20   young

2 xyz   3000   26  middle

3 ijk   4000     32 middle

4 mno   5000     50  old

Comment: i am not getting idea bcz no relation there http://stackoverflow.com/users/1498857/nanny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select empid,empname, salary, grp.groupname from employee emp left
outer join  groupname grp 
on ( emp.age > grp.[min] and emp.age <
grp.[max])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Empid, Empname, Salary, Age,Groupname
from Employee,GroupNameTable
where Age between Min and max
```